# Listbox Sorting based on TextBox value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can I sort ListBox items using TextBox enterd value.
The match case ListBox Items show top of list box
Here is my code

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="67,39,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CustomerSort,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <ListBox Margin="67,79,185,26" Background="LightYellow"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerColloction}"/>
</Grid>
```

C# code

```
 public class Customers
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        CustomerColloction = new ObservableCollection<Customers>();
        CustomerColloction.Add(new Customers() { Name = "AAA", Age = 25 });
        CustomerColloction.Add(new Customers() { Name = "AA", Age = 25 });
        CustomerColloction.Add(new Customers() { Name = "BBB", Age = 26 });
        CustomerColloction.Add(new Customers() { Name = "BB", Age = 24 });
        CustomerColloction.Add(new Customers() { Name = "AAAA", Age = 13 });
        CustomerColloction.Add(new Customers() { Name = "BB", Age = 11 });
        CustomerColloction.Add(new Customers() { Name = "XYZ", Age = 44 });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Customers> CustomerColloction { get; set; }

    private String _CustomerSort = String.Empty;
    public String CustomerSort
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomerSort;
        }
        set
       {
            _CustomerSort = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomerSort");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I want to get the result like if we enter AA in TextBox, To Show sorting item form list box

- AA
- AAA
- AAAA
- BB
- BB
- BBB
- XYZ

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? When the user enters AA as the input, how do you intend to use that for sort?

Comment: The match case text want to display first

Comment: Maybe some Linq? `_result.OrderBy(i => i.Name);`

Comment: @Luis Lavieri I want to display based on entered text in text box value

Comment: too vague my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set combobox and set drop down mode
Better to sort observable collection and set to ListBox CustomerColloction.OrderBy(q=>q.Name).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

I can see its a pretty vauge requirement but just to give you an idea you can manipulate your bound object collection like this to achieve similar results

Following code has been typed by a mobile device and is not verified..

```
CustomerColloction.Where(p=>p.name.Contains(CustomerSort)).OrderBy(q=>q.Name).ToList().Add(CustomerColloction.where(r=>r.name.Contains(CustomerSort)=false).OrderBy(s=>s.Name).toList()
```

And in setter of youe CustomerSort property raise notification for you bound collection

Comment: But this not affecting UI

Comment: Inside Customer sort property

Comment: No, this should be getter of your CustomerColloction